# Javascript Regular expression to match the length of values in both sides of a range

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate postal code ranges using Javascript and the framework that supplies the country specific validation rule to the method uses regular expressions.

Is there a way to validate (using regex match/test/any other js regex functions) if the number of characters on both sides of the range delimiter (its colon in this case) is same ?

e.g.
`85001:85255` or `A9A 9AA:A9A 9ZZ` is valid (both sides have same number of characters)

Whereas, 
`85001:255` or `A9A 9AA:9ZZ` is invalid (different number of characters in x vs y for x:y)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one paradigm of regular expressions is that they cannot count.

However, you can "hack it" like so if you know the max length of the number of chars on a side. Assuming a max-length of 4:

```
var code = '8500:1234';
/\b((.:.)|(..:..)|(...:...)|(....:....))\b/.test(code)
```

if you don't want to write this by hand, you can generate the regexp like so:

```
var max_length = 6;
var delimiter = ':';

var regexp = [];
for (var i=1; i<=max_length; ++i) {
  var side = '';
  for (var j=1; j<=i; ++j) {
    side += '.';
  }
  regexp.push('(' + side + delimiter + side + ')');
}
regexp = '\b(' + regexp.join('|') + ')\b';
regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
```

Comment: You should probably use start/end anchors instead of word boundaries, as using `\b` will give a false positive for the given example of `A9A 9AA:9ZZ`.

Answer (score 2):

Here a little bit less verbose version of RegExp profided by @tak3r

```
var r = /^(.{1}:.{1}|.{2}:.{2}|.{3}:.{3}|.{4}:.{4}|.{5}:.{5}|.{6}:.{6}|.{7}:.{7})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split the tokens and compare the lengths:

```
var range = "123:567";

var tokens = range.split(":");

var valid = tokens[0].length === tokens[1].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareValues(str){

    var str_array = str.split(':');

    return (str_array[0].length===str_array[1].length);
}


alert(compareValues('A9A 9AA:A9A 9ZZ'));
alert(compareValues('85001:255'));
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EU7uB/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture parentheses on both side of the colon and then test their
Lengths for equality.

```
var myString = "85001:85255";
var myRegexp = /^([\w][\w\s]+):([\w][\w\s]+)$/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);

if (match[1].length === match[2].length) { 
    alert("There is a match!")
}
else { 
    alert("Not a match")
}
//There is a match!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an added thought, given your two postal codes:

```
var s1 = "85001:85255";
var s2 = "A9A 9AA:A9A 9ZZ";
```

This regex will test for a pattern of either 5 digits before and after the colon, OR 3 of either a letter or number followed by a space and then another 3 of either a letter or number before and after the colon.

```
//var re = /(((\w|\d){3}\s(\w|\d){3}:(\w|\d){3}\s(\w|\d){3})|(\d{5}:\d{5}))/;
var re = /((\w{3}\s\w{3}:\w{3}\s\w{3})|(\d{5}:\d{5}))/;
alert(re.test(s1));
alert(re.test(s2));
```

Comment: You can shorten this, as word characters `\w` include digits `\d`.